# Is the > symbol necessary when selecting a child element in CSS?

Tags: css

```
div > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

doesn't appear to evaluate any differently than

```
div p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But would there be an effect I am unaware of? It seems that using the > is more proper style, at least.

Comment: `>` is used for an immediate descendent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference; `>` is "immediately follows". So your `div > p` would apply to the `p` here:

```
<div>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

but not here:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Text here</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

A more detailed description can be found within the [CSS specification for child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Comment: What would be the difference then between the two former and 
    `div * p`
?

Comment: @JasonNikesh `div * p` means a p element that's a descendant of a div element but not a direct child.

Comment: @Alohci More simply, it means it's a descendant *of a descendant* of a div element.

Comment: @JasonNikesh See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors for details on descendant selectors.

Comment: @AdrianWragg - Yes, if you prefer. I was trying to make it clearer what the use case for such a construct might be.

Comment: @AdrianWragg So for my clarity, `div > p` is only direct children, `div p` includes direct children and all descendants, and `div * p` excludes direct children, but includes further descendants?

Comment: @JasonNikesh Those are all correct, yes, although you might want to read up on the exact usage of "*" - it just means "match any tag", it doesn't have any special usage specific to descendancy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example it might help you ...

```
div#container > ul {
```

border: 1px solid black;
}

.......

```
<div id="container">   <ul>
  <li> List Item
    <ul>
       <li> Child </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> List Item </li>
  <li> List Item </li>
  <li> List Item </li>   </ul> </div>
```

A selector of #container > ul will only target the uls which are direct children of the div with an id of container. It will not target, for instance, the ul that is a child of the first li.

For this reason, there are performance benefits in using the child combinator. In fact, it's recommended particularly when working with JavaScript-based CSS selector engines.
 .......
Read this : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048
it will help you .

Answer (score 1):

`div > p` selects the direct child `p` (only the sons),
`div p` selects all its children `p`, now matter how deep it is in the hierarchy (including the grandsons and great grandsons).

Answer (score 1):

```
div>p
```

indicates a P which is a DIRECT child of div

```
div p
```

indicates a p that is descendent of div, not

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbawp69w/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The > selector is used to select child elements of a particular elemnent.